# How to disable Google Chrome auto update?

Tags: google-chrome, auto-update

Does anyone know how to disable Google Chrome for being automatic update itself, it cause my web application always change?

I have tried using the Google Update ADM templates provided on this page or as described in [this wikiHow article](http://www.wikihow.com/Completely-Disable-Google-Chrome-Update):

Set the value of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Update\AutoUpdateCheckPeriodMinutes` to the `REG_DWORD` value of "0".

but there is no Google in my Registry Editor, so I can't set it.

Comment: I think this is because you have installed Chrome without being an administrator. In this case Chrome does not install system-wide Google Update and thus you don't have such registry.

Comment: for newer versions of chrome, simply delete (or zip backup) the 'Update' folder on `C:\Program Files\Google\Update` or in x64 systems: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Update`. you may also delete/rename the GoogleUpdate.exe in that folder. If you have installed chrome in custom path, goto chrome.exe location (right-click on Google Chrome shortcut and choose Open file location), then go back (up) two folders to reach that Update folder path.

Comment: In my case the problem was not update per se, but an annoying warning from Google: _This version of Chrome is no longer supported_. I found a nice solution: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-smart-switcher/dgdmfclijcondkaobmpgbmibaaocfdpj.

Comment: I see "This question does not meet Stack Overflow guidelines", well I disagree - I think it's a great question, and also relevant for software devs

Comment: The policy and registry strategies you all have asked and answered about are all possibly correct.  But, some update policies are only honoured for computers which are part of a domain (Active Directory).  See here - https://admx.help/?Category=ChromeEnterprise&Policy=Google.Policies.Update::Pol_AutoUpdateCheckPeriod

Answer (score -20, accepted):

1. On your Chrome browser's address bar, type in 'about:plugins' and hit ENTER.
2. Find the plugin called 'Google Update' and click disable.
3. Restart your browser for the changes to take effect.

Comment: does not work, no "Google Update" in Chrome 34, Mac.

Comment: I was able to disable the Google Update plugin as Amar suggested however, Chrome still applied updates.  After adding the registry settings @absynce suggested they finally disabled.  The about screen now shows Updates are disabled by the administrator.

Comment: Google Update doesn't appear in Chrome (v42) in the plugins page. Have they removed this option?

Comment: You need to use fillowing method for Chrome v42.  http://www.wikihow.com/Completely-Disable-Google-Chrome-Update

Comment: For later versions than 42, you need to use http://www.wikihow.com/Completely-Disable-Google-Chrome-Update

Comment: The link to wikihow Amar commented does not work for me on Chrome 50. I had to use the Luds answer to rename the update directory

Comment: The 'about:plugins' is no longer available after Chrome 56.

Comment: For latest versions, use following steps:
1. Go to "msconfig" from Win+R
2. Go to Service tab
3. Uncheck both "Google Update Service" boxes.
4. Click OK and Restart computer to save changes.

Comment: I found that this works for Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53691313/2334415. I wonder if any of the answers here work for Mac.

Answer (score 210):

<sup>Have spent a long time trying to disable updates (literally hours, reading forums and testing various (some exotic) solutions), and this was driving me crazy. But there what seems an **infallible solution** (see further down).</sup>

Even using the official Google page with the templates did NOTHING: https://support.google.com/installer/answer/146164?hl=en

I followed scrupulously the instructions of that page, the keys in the registry are all correct, but still going to the "About Google Chrome" when the program is opened, I can see the wheel going around and a few seconds later the update is forced and done.

I have tried using the standalone installer of Google, on a Windows 8.1 machine 64Bits - and yes all the keys are set to :

Dword: AutoUpdateCheckPeriodMinutes Value: 0
Dword: DisableAutoUpdateChecksCheckboxValue Value: 1
Dword: UpdateDefault Value: 0
Dword: Update{8A69D345-D564-463C-AFF1-A69D9E530F96} Value: 0
(this last one requires the service(s) to not be disabled - gupdate/gupdatem)

... both in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Update AND HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Policies\Google\Update since it is a  64-bit machine.

So the radical solution to prevent the auto-update, if that helps anyone, is to just purely sort the program responsible for the updates itself!  (Just deleting it, OR saving a copy, OR renaming it OR even better just in case I one day need to do an update: Zip the content for future potential re-use).

Easy **solution** :
1- Go to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\ and find the folder "update".
2- There are a couple of options to choose from:

```
 A) first method: Rename the folder:
```

- Right click > **Rename** > from Update.bak  to Update2.bak for example.
- Now launch Chrome: NO MORE UPDATES!! since it can not find the update program !! **Finished**.

  B) second method: Zip the folder:
- **Zip the entire folder** by making an archive. (Right click the "Update" folder > Send to Compressed (zip) folder)
- A window might ask you to backup/zip and place it on the desktop, click yes. (message: *Windows cannot create the compressed folders here. Do you want to be placed on the desktop instead?*)
- Move the newly created zip file to the original location. New window security might pop up > click continue. (message: *You need administrator permission to copy this file*). [This will be what to unzip if one day you decide to update Chrome - Just remember that when unzipped it will have the following structure: Update > Update > then all the content of the folder. Remember to move everything from inside the second update folder (copy paste) one level up so that is becoming: Update > then all the content of the folder].
- Now that you have a copy just **delete** the "Update" folder.
- Now launch Chrome: NO MORE UPDATES!! since it can not find the update program !! **Finished**.

Comment: One additional thing to check on top of this is your Task Scheduler. I had two tasks in there scheduled to run daily to update Chrome. I see those tasks on every machine and VM I maintain with Chrome on it.

Comment: One may rename the directory from `Update` to `Update.disabled`.

Comment: See this alternative answer for renaming: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45064002/363573

Comment: I realize this is an older thread, but I wanted to say for me, this was the best solution. Searching my box's registry, I found none of the Dword values in any key. Start with this solution

Comment: Where is this on OS X?

Comment: One may need to use Task Manager to stop Google crash handler processes first before renaming the folder.

Comment: Instead of renaming the file, you should instead revoke all permissions (which includes read and execute) to it, so other processes can't just "fix" the files on you. Especially relevant for Windows system files (e.g. Cortana). Right click > Security > Advanced > Remove all entries and click Disable Inheritance

Comment: I am going to try renaming the folder but I am getting permission denied right now. I am using a tool called "Unlocker" which should rename it for me after the next reboot. Chrome update messages are disgusting piece of garbage because they ruin my browser experience, especially when I'm typing.

Comment: Found the `update` folder in `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Google`

Comment: somehow `Chrome` was able to update itself even renaming the `update` folder in `v86`

Comment: The first method works for me. After you installed a specific version, remove all chrome running process via the taskbar then rename the update folder.

Comment: @elgato True for me. My chrome is version 86 but received the copy highlight feature from 90.

Comment: At some point a few weeks ago, it seems my `Update` folder was somehow restored and Chrome updated itself. Therefore, I created a file named `Update` to prevent the folder from ever being created again. Seems to work so far.

Comment: Even if I do this, chrome keeps asking me to restart it to update it. What a disgusting.

Answer (score 54):

This is just a trick to stop auto update of **Google Chrome** in Mac OS.

1. Go to **Applications** Folder in Finder.
2. Right click **Google Chrome** and select **Show Package Contents**.
3. Go to **Contents** directory.
4. Open **Info.plist** file with **XCode** or other text editor.
5. Change the value of the key: **KSUpdateURL** to an invalid URL.
   something like 
   https://tools.google.com/service/invalidurl
6. Overwrite **Info.plist** file.
7. Restart **Google Chrome**.

Finally go to **Google Chrome** **Settings** / **About**.
You will see Update always fails because the update url was set to an invalid one.

[image: Update Always Fails]

Comment: It was successful for me! Thanks.

Comment: This method wouldn't let me restart Google Chrome.  It just gave me a message to the effect that "Google Chrome stopped unexpectedly", with the option to report it, but it wouldn't ever start.    
   
I also completely removed the KSUpdateURL key and string, with the same inability to restart after editing it.

Comment: @MetaSean just unsign it with https://github.com/steakknife/unsign and then open with right click holding control and then press open in contextual menu

Comment: After restarting my computer this seemed to crash chrome on startup for me.

Comment: It was an answer for the quite old versions.

Comment: Editing `/etc/hosts` and pointing `tools.google.com` to `127.0.0.1` also works, and doesn't require restarting Chrome.

Comment: I am not sure if the Chrome team has changed the strategy to manage `Info.plist` file, the value of `KSUpdateURL` will be overridden back again after we change it. So this solution does not work for me.

Comment: This is working for me so far (have not restarted my entire machine....just the browser)

Comment: For those of you who changed it and crashed Chrome, the original value for that key is `https://tools.google.com/service/update2`.

Comment: @ThrowAwayAccount I guess it doesn't work anymore. I tried /etc/hosts but a couple of weeks later Chrome updated anyway.

Comment: Blocking the update server using `hosts` file works perfectly, it's giving this error message when checking for update `KSServerUpdateRequest fetch failed. Could not connect to the server.`

Comment: Great answer, and it looked like it worked - unfortunately however it seems the changes to Info.plist are automatically reverted, so this was not a solution in the end (maybe removing write permissions to the file would get around that ...?) - so I went with one of the other suggestions above and added "tools.google.com" to /etc/hosts - hopefully that works ...

Answer (score 37):

We had a problem printing with v49something.

I blocked tools.google.com on localhost temporarily so that I could install previous version and prevent updating to the version that is breaking the label printing.

So, in /etc/hosts I added:

```
0.0.0.0 tools.google.com
```

Not a perfect solution, but was perfect for us.

Comment: This is a great solution, it does seem to disable the update, but the only weird thing is that occasionally my Chrome updates anyway! I imagine there might be a cached copy of the update somewhere, any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't help. Chrome updates anyway.

Comment: Yea for me this only makes chrome fail when checking if there are updates in the "about chrome" page. But chrome eventually manages to upgrade anyway.

Answer (score 22):

**For Windows only**

To completely disable automatic Chrome updates create/edit the following registry keys/dwords under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Update`:

- Dword: `AutoUpdateCheckPeriodMinutes`
  Value: `0`
- Dword: `DisableAutoUpdateChecksCheckboxValue`
  Value: `1`
- Dword: `UpdateDefault`
  Value: `0`
- Dword: **`Update{8A69D345-D564-463C-AFF1-A69D9E530F96}`**
  Value: `0`

**This last one was the money for me.** Until I added it updates were enabled in `chrome://chrome`.

**Note:** On 64-bit machines running 32-bit Chrome you may need to put the dwords under the following key instead: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Policies\Google\Update`.

I created a GitHub gist [powershell script](https://gist.github.com/absynce/7667bd32e632e72f406f) to create the dwords under both `Policies` *and* `Wow6432Node\Policies`.

Comment: Be careful with disabling Chrome updates in this way. I've found that eventually an out-of-date message pops up.

Comment: @absynce - So what do we do now?

Comment: @HairOfTheDog The string `Update{XXX-XXX...}` may change from update to update. Check the directory where Chrome is installed then open the directory: `<CHROME_INSTALL_DIR>\Update\Download`. Values to use for the current platform should be present there.

Comment: Chrome 56 (decided to stop updating this sh..). With disabled autoupdate (all services and other) the popup appears and menu icon changes to exclamation after a few months w/o updates. Fix helps, but on first run it still asks me for update. Once. And then, when I say No, there is no more of this stuff. Just be warned about first run notification after fix.

Answer (score 20):

**New Answer by  12-9-2018**

I am facing same problem when I am try to use GooleChrome **V-68** it tryto update **V-71**.
Then I get solution by change the name of file `GoogleUpdate.exe`

For Windows 10 file path:_ `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Update`

Just rename the the file name of **GoogleUpdate.exe** to any name.

Check my screenshot for more understand.

[image]

Now it show Error when try to get update version install :P 
[image]

Answer (score 13):

For latest versions, use following steps:

1. Go to "msconfig" from Win+R
2. Go to Service tab
3. Uncheck both "Google Update Service" boxes.
4. Click OK and Restart computer to save changes.

Comment: This is working here on Chrome v 80, as of 2020-03.

Comment: No effect for Chrome 98 - was updated to Chrome 99

Answer (score 12):

The simplest method on Windows 10 with recent versions of Chrome as of early 2020. No registry hack, Powershell or GPO required :

1. Open the `Computer Management` app with elevated rights: type it in the taskbar search, then click `Run as administrator` on the menu
2. Go to `Service and Applications` -> `Services`
3. Find `Google Update Service (gupdate)` and `Google Update Service (gupdatem)`
4. For both services, right-click, select `Properties` and set `Startup type:` to Disabled.

Tested and working on Google Chrome v 80, Win 10 / 1909 / 18363.592, as of March 2020.

Comment: No effect for Chrome 98 - was updated to Chrome 99

Answer (score 9):

many unstable solutions
I prefer to edit the host file

```
/etc/hosts

127.0.0.1 dl.google.com
127.0.0.1 tools.google.com
```

Comment: Unfortunately my chrome updated today with these in my host file.

Answer (score 8):

Just add the object yourself using `regedit`:

Under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies,

- Create new Key, "Google"
- In "Google", create new Key, "Update"
- In "Update" go to that key and create Dword, "AutoUpdateCheckPeriodMinutes" which automatically value set to 0, just double check and change if needed.

All done!

Restart might be needed.

Comment: According to https://www.chromium.org/administrators/turning-off-auto-updates this has stopped working after 8/2014. Now if you set the value to 0 it will still check for updates every 77 hours anyway.

Answer (score 7):

We automate the Chrome install and disable the auto update with Chef. When Chef tried to rename the entire Update directory, it failed with the "Access denied" error. Because Chef cannot click Yes when a security prompt comes up, the renaming of the entire Update directory does not work for us. We rename only the updater executable with

```
rename GoogleUpdate.exe GoogleUpdate_disabled.tmp
```

The entire Chef resource is

```
batch 'disable_chrome_update' do
  code <<-EOF
    cd "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Update"
    rename GoogleUpdate.exe GoogleUpdate_disabled.tmp
  EOF
  only_if {File.exists?("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Update\\GoogleUpdate.exe")}
end
```

Comment: Renaming the whole folder also doesn't seem to work if Chrome is currently running (because the _GoogleCrashHandler.exe_ inside this folder tree is actively running as a background process). So renaming just _GoogleUpdate.exe_ instead works well if you don't want to quit Chrome.

Answer (score 6):

I have tried all of these options and none seem to work. Sometimes I actually got a message "GoogleUpdate is disabled" when I checked the "About" page, but somehow a week later it was still updated.

Now I just add GoogleUpdate to the firewall and block internet access. If I check the "About" page I get a message it is updating and after a few seconds that it can't update and I should check my firewall.

Answer (score 6):

I use Commodo Firewall HIPS feature to stop googleupdate.exe even executing. I have set no rules for gooleupdate.exe internet access but if somehow it does get to execute I will get a popup asking if I want to grant it internet access.

Currently trying to bring myself to move away from chrome and as many google products as possible after realising the effort they have gone to, to thwart the tiny minority of people who actually regedited the old auto update and their desire to have more control over your machines than you do.

Answer (score 5):

simple and working

goto  C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\update

rename update folder name

Answer (score 5):

Sort of "official method" is listed here:
http://www.wikihow.com/Completely-Disable-Google-Chrome-Update

In a nutshell:

1) download http://www.wikihow.com/Completely-Disable-Google-Chrome-Update

2) install it using gpedit.msc (click on Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates, then select 'Add/Remove Templates...' in 'Action' menu)

3) disable Chrome update in
Computer Configuration
    Administrative Templates
        Classic Administrative Templates
            Google
                Google Update
                      Applications
                        Google Chrome
by setting 'Update Policy Override' to 'Disabled'

Answer (score 4):

### Disable Chrome Version Auto Update - All-in-One Solution

With some of the answers here for **disabling Google Chrome automatic updates**, I've come up with a solution that uses specific group policy settings and also a PowerShell startup script to rename the GoogleUpdate.exe, disable the correlated services, and disable the correlated Task Scheduler tasks.

I'm posting as an answer in case someone else needs an all-in-one solution that can easily be expanded on (or toned down some) if needed and potentially save them some time.

### PowerShell (Startup Script)

```
## -- Rename the Google Update executable file
$Chrome = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe";
If(Test-Path($Chrome)){Rename-Item -Path $Chrome -NewName "Old_GoogleUpdate.exe.old" -Force};

$Chrome = "$env:ProgramFiles\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe";
If(Test-Path($Chrome)){Rename-Item -Path $Chrome -NewName "Old_GoogleUpdate.exe.old" -Force};

## -- Stop and disable the Google Update services that run to update Chrome
$GUpdateServices = (Get-Service | ?{$_.DisplayName -match "Google Update Service"}).Name;
$GUpdateServices | % {
    $status = (Get-Service -Name $_).Status;
    If($status -ne "Stopped"){Stop-Service $_ -Force};
    $sType  = (Get-Service -Name $_).StartType;
    If($sType -ne "Disabled"){Set-Service $_ -StartupType Disabled};
    };

## -- Disable Chrome Update Scheduled Tasks
$GUdateTasks = (Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\" -TaskName "*GoogleUpdateTask*");
$GUdateTasks | % {If($_.State -ne "Disabled"){Disable-ScheduledTask -TaskName $_.TaskName}};
```

### Group Policy Settings (Computer Configuration)

Be sure the Software Restriction policy blocks EXE file types at a minimum for these specific folder locations but the defaults should work fine if you leave as-is.

[image]

---

### Additional Resources

- [Set Chrome Browser policies on managed PCs](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187202)

  - Be sure to check and confirm you have the latest Chrome [policy templates](https://dl.google.com/dl/edgedl/chrome/policy/policy_templates.zip) to load into your policy definitions for group policy.

Comment: What tool do you use to generate a view of the GPO content like that ?

Comment: Group Policy Management Console but see https://kb.netwrix.com/759 for a breakdown that may help as well.

Comment: Thanks! For others who might read this, the functionality I was wondering about is called "Group Policy Results Wizard" in GPMC.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Mac OS. Keep the version that you need and then following step help you stop updating chrome permanently.

**To Disable auto update:-**

Empty these directories:

```
~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/
```

Then change the permissions on these folders named 'GoogleSoftwareUpdate' so that there's no owner and no **read/write/execute** permissions. In terminal:

```
cd /Library/Google/
sudo chown nobody:nogroup GoogleSoftwareUpdate
sudo chmod 000 GoogleSoftwareUpdate

cd ~/Library/Google/
sudo chown nobody:nogroup GoogleSoftwareUpdate
sudo chmod 000 GoogleSoftwareUpdate
```

Then do the same for the folder Google one level up.

```
cd /Library/
sudo chown nobody:nogroup Google
sudo chmod 000 Google
cd ~/Library/                                                                                                                    
sudo chown nobody:nogroup Google
sudo chmod 000 Google
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 3):

the best way to disable Google chrome auto update is as follows

- Go to oldversion dot com and download old version of google
- Use Advanced unsinstaller to completely uninstall current (Updated) version. This will also get rid of registry entries
- Download update freezer and create a shortcut on desktop
- Disable internet
- Restart PC
- With internet disabled, install old version of Chrome
- Ope Update Freezer and Disable Google auto update

You are done

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**

Delete the folder C:\Program Files\Google\Update

---

Here is what I do to stop auto update of chrome. Since you want to disable auto update, you may be installing chrome using the [offline installer](https://support.google.com/installer/answer/126299?hl=en). If not, then I recommend that you use that; it makes more sense for *you* anyway! Select the second option that says "Alternate installer for all user accounts", but you may also choose the other option. Anyway, *this process should work for all kinds of installation of chrome.*

1. Install chrome and go to about page with the internet connected. This is to trigger the update process.
2. Open task manager, go to `Processes` tab and look for the process named something like `google updater`. You may need to click on 'Show processes from all users' button if your uac is turned on
3. Right-click on google updater process name and select `open file location`. Once location is opened in the explorer, **end the process**
4. Delete the file corresponding to that ended process (by now it is located and selected in the explorer, as was done in step 3; for most this is C:\Program Files\Google\Update, but will be different if you had chosen to install for a single user)
5. open `Scheduled tasks` (by typing `sched`... in start perhaps)
6. Click on 'Task Scheduler Library` on the left and on the right side search for entries corresponding to google product updates. Disable or delete those tasks

You should be good to go! Auto update is not only disabled but killed forever.

P.S.: step 5 and 6 are simply for overkilling :-)

Answer (score 3):

Simple hacky way is to rename **Updates** folder in *C:\Program Files (x86)\Google*.
Done it to freeze my chrome at 44 untill proper NPAPI replacement is supported by majority of plugins.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the most upvoted answer, it might be good to remove these as well for the sake of cleanness.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**For Ubuntu:**

1. go to 'Software & Updates'.
2. click 'Other Software' tab.
3. Uncheck the next checkbox 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main'

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Worked for Windows Server 2008 and Chrome v64:

- Rename "Update" directory to "Update2"
- Create blank file called "Update" (without extension)

Answer (score 2):

On Windows OS:

1) open following file for edit (as an admin): `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`
(this file has no extension)

2) on the bottom, add one line: `127.0.0.1 tools.google.com`

3) save the file

4) enjoy old Chrome

Comment: @BitcoinMurderousManiac - that's the host which is used by Chrome Upgrade service to a download newest version.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows users, you may follow the steps in
[Google Chrome Enterprise Help - Manage Chrome updates (Windows)](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6350036).

Just follow step 1: Install Google Update > Get the Google Update policy template & step 2: Configure auto-updates > Turn off Chrome Browser auto-updates.

If everything is configured correctly, you will see "Updates are disabled by your administrator." in Google Chrome settings About Chrome section after you reboot the pc.
[image: configured successful screenshot]

Comment: Can you clarify the procedure please? I can not understand a thing to be honest.

Comment: The detailed steps are in the link attached, have you took a look inside?

Answer (score 1):

For Mac OS, you'll have to remove permissions, but leave the directory

```
$ sudo chown root:wheel GoogleSoftwareUpdate
$ sudo chmod = GoogleSoftwareUpdate
```

Comment: This is **The Way** for macOS

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of Chrome 44 and go back to 43 I downloaded a stand-alone version of chrome 43 which is an .exe file and I just double clicked on it and it was installed on my computer WITHOUT updating to Chrome 44, to find the link to Chrome 43 have a look to  the bottom of this page [Google Chrome 64-bit Offline Installer| 45.7 MB](http://www.neowin.net/news/google-chrome-43-released-now-available-for-download)  or go to [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31708631/cannot-stop-chrome-from-updating-from-43-to-44/31724999#31724999).

Have Fun :)

Answer (score 0):

To Disable Google Chrome Auto Updates in Windows:

- Goto "**C:\Program Files (x86)\Google**"
- Rename the directory "**Update**" to "**Update2**". 
  Directory delete or rename may not be possible due to the running processes with respect to the corresponding executables in the directory. In that use the [Unlocker](https://softpedia-secure-download.com/dl/6a57764bd295a1d9ce81d51d5324a480/5a7af72f/100068439/software/tweak/Unlocker%20x64%201.9.2.msi) tool to forcefully delete or rename the directory.
- Restart Chrome and Go to **Help -> About Google Chrome**. 
  Here we can see the message as "***update check failed***"

That's it !!

Comment: Rename didn't work. It will stop the update instantly but after a week or after few hours, it gets auto updated again.

Answer (score 0):

After wrestling a lot, found an uncomplicated solution for **Mac**. Hope this will help.

1. Leave it to upgrade.
2. Then go to application, right click on chrome app and open package contents.
3. Navigate further as `/Applications/Google Chrome old.app/Contents/Frameworks/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Versions`
4. You will find a `current` folder. **Delete this :)**
5. Restart chrome and enjoy..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, even removing the update folder doesn't fully stop auto updates. But you can download Chromium browser instead of Google Chrome. It's essentially the same browser but it doesn't have the Google branding and there are no auto updates.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, you can shut down the automatic update function through Chrome browser settings. Or you can do it via altering system registry entries. You can view detailed tips here http://blog.doofix.com/how-to-stop-google-chrome-from-automatic-update/
Hope this helps!

Answer (score -3):

On a Mac, you can change the update frequency to a very large value.  See:

- https://support.google.com/installer/answer/147176?hl=en&ctx=go

For myself, I ran the following command in Terminal:

```
defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 18000000
```

Comment: The article states: 'Note: The maximum interval is 24 hours.'