# Chrome version 44 has some issue with selenium test

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium and Chrome to write a test, yesterday when my Chrome updated from 43 to 44 my test got some problems with action.sendkey("arrow.down") and etc.

I tried to uninstall Chrome and install Chrome 43 but as soon as I do it updates its self to 44 !!!
I also tried chromedriver 2.16 but it did not work too.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to [Keys.ENTER, Keys.TAB, Keys.SPACE are not working on Chrome 44](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=1159) and [Input.dispatchKeyEvents handles some keys incorrectly](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=513768).

The problem was fixed. You need to give it some time and upgrade as soon as a new chromium release come out, or revert back to 43. Or, install `chromium` [from trunk](https://download-chromium.appspot.com/).

**Update Regarding AutoUpdate**

You can refer [How can I disable Google Chrome auto update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483087/how-can-i-disable-google-chrome-auto-update) for that

Comment: Thanks for your help, do you have any idea how long it takes that they give out the fixed version of chrome?

Comment: @LoveJava I suggest subscribe to the issue and wait for an update. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to uninstall Chrome and install Chrome 43 but as soon as I do it updates its self to 44, what should i do?

Comment: thanks for the heads up - this drove me crazy the past few days and altho I suspected the chrome update, wasn't able to uninstall on the entire range of machines that we use!! Will await the next release eagerly - plus one!

Answer (score 0):

This issue will be solved soon when they release the new version, but now just uninstall Chrome 44 then install chrome 43 and disable its automatic uploading.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the below issues on chrome 44:

1. `element.click` does not work always, I have to wait for a couple of secs before I click. I used css selector. This worked fine on Chrome 43.
2. `driver.findElement` keeps throwing `NoSuchElementException` although element is on the page.
3. finding any element after page reload or new page load results in `StaleElementException`.
4. WebDriver instantiation and teardown is not working as intended: it opens multiple blank instances on Chrome 44.

I am blocked majorly on Chrome. I have [filed Chromium bug #515171](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=515171) but I am not sure if they will look at it.