# cannot stop Chrome from updating from 43 to 44

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium and Chrome to write a web test, yesterday my Chrome updated to 44 and now my test does not work, I know that it is an issue with Chrome 44 and we need to wait till the new version is given out.
So I am trying to go bake to chrome 43, i do:

1) Uninstall chrome 44

2) Install chrome 43

but as soon as the installation is done it automatically opens the chrome and it is 44 again !! I went to Run->Service.msc and disabled my chrome to update automatically, but it does not work. I remove the Update folder in User->Myname->AppData->Local->Google->Update but it does not work,
and there is nothing related to updating at chrome://plugins.

I AM STUCK

PLEASE HELP :(
I did all sulosion posted on line but non of them worked,

Comment: Have you tried solutions posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483087/how-can-i-disable-google-chrome-auto-update?

Comment: yes, and as I said there is no "Google Update" plugin there :( and I think if even it is there, it would not help because it prevent chrome from further updates after 44

Comment: You could try to use a stand-alone Chrome (without installation). For version 43 it is https://dl.google.com/chrome/win/4ED6DD719811795B/43.0.2357.134_chrome_installer.exe (warning: this link may expire soon). After downloading the file unzip the file. You will get a file called `chrome.7z`. Unzip this again (using 7-zip) and you will have a portable version of Chrome (43).

Comment: @RobW the link gave me this:  "43.0.2357.134_chrome_installer.exe" and when  double click it nothing happens

Comment: @SinaGolestanirad I said **unzip** it (twice). E.g. with http://www.7-zip.org

Comment: @Robw I did it and now I have a GoogleUpdate.exe, what to do next?

Comment: @SinaGolestanirad What's the file size of 43.0.2357.134_chrome_installer.exe? It should be around 41MB, and does not contain GoogleUpdate.exe.

Comment: @Robw It has: a folder called "43.0.2357.134" and chrome.exe and wow_helper.exe

Comment: @Robw what should i do now to get it used by selenium (JAVA), by the way your help means a lot to me, thanks indeed :)

Comment: @SinaGolestanirad Set the Chrome binary to the path to the chrome.exe within your directory.

Comment: @Robw now it is throwing this error : INFO: Command failed to close cleanly. Destroying forcefully (v2). org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog@55040f2f Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: chrome failed to start ....

Comment: @Robw finally I got it working :) please post your comment as the actual answer

Comment: @SinaGolestanirad The link to the old version of Chrome that I've suggested will expire soon. So that'd make my answer a bit useless. You could however post an answer yourself and explain the steps that you've followed to get your setup to work (including how you've solved the last error).

Comment: @robw Could you please tell me how and where I can find those links for stand-alone chromes

Answer (score 1):

Have spent a loooong time trying to disable updates (literally hours, reading forums and testing various (some exotic) solutions), and this was driving me crazy. But there what seems an **infallible solution** (see further down).

Even using the official Google page with the templates did NOTHING : https://support.google.com/installer/answer/146164?hl=en

I followed scrupulously the instructions of that page, the keys in the registry are all correct, but still going to the "About Google Chrome" when the program is opened, I can see the wheel going around and a few seconds later the update is forced and done.

I have tried using the standalone installer of Google, on a Windows 8.1 machine 64Bits - and yes all the keys are set to :

Dword: AutoUpdateCheckPeriodMinutes Value: 0
Dword: DisableAutoUpdateChecksCheckboxValue Value: 1
Dword: UpdateDefault Value: 0
Dword: Update{8A69D345-D564-463C-AFF1-A69D9E530F96} Value: 0

... both in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Update AND HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Policies\Google\Update since it is a  64-bit machine.

So the radical solution to prevent the auto-update, if that helps anyone, is to just purely sort the program responsible for the updates itself!  (Just deleting it, OR saving a copy, OR renaming it OR even better just in case I one day need to do an update: Zip the content for future potential re-use).

Easy **solution** :
1- Go to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\ and find the folder "update".
2- There are a couple of options to choose from:

```
 A) first method: Rename the folder:
```

- Right click > **Rename** > from Update.bak  to Update2.bak for example.
- Now launch Chrome: NO MORE UPDATES!! since it can not find the update program !! **Finished**.

```
 B) second method: Zip the folder:
```

- **Zip the entire folder** by making an archive. (Right click the "Update" folder > Send to Compressed (zip) folder)
- A window might ask you to backup/zip and place it on the desktop, click yes. (message: *Windows cannot create the compressed folders here. Do you want to be placed on the desktop instead?*)
- Move the newly created zip file to the original location. A new window security might pop up > click continue. (message: *You need administrator permission to copy this file*). [This will be what to unzip if one day you decide to update Chrome - Just remember that when unzipped it will have the following structure : Update > Update > then all the content of the folder. Remember to move everything from inside the second update folder (copy paste) one level up so that is becomes : Update > then all the content of the folder]. 
- Now that you have a copy just **delete** the "Update" folder.
- Now launch Chrome: NO MORE UPDATES!! since it can not find the update program !! **Finished**.

Good luck and Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/turning-off-auto-updates)

Turning off Auto-Updates on Windows

To turn off auto-updates of Google Chrome on Windows, you need to instruct Google Update to not update it.  To do this, you can either:

Use the Google Update ADM templates provided on this page or as described in [this article](http://www.google.com/support/installer/bin/answer.py?answer=146164).

> Set the value of
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Update\AutoUpdateCheckPeriodMinutes
> to the REG_DWORD value of "0".

You can check for Mac and Linux in the first Link

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of Chrome 44 and go back to 43 I downloaded a stand-alone version of chrome 43 which is an .exe file and I just double clicked on it and it was installed on my computer WITHOUT updating to Chrome 44, to find the link to Chrome 43 have a look to RobW comments to my question above and if the link is stale you can just Google for Chrome Stand-alone, or go to the bottom of this page [Google Chrome 64-bit Offline Installer| 45.7 MB](http://www.neowin.net/news/google-chrome-43-released-now-available-for-download).

Have Fun :)

Answer (score 0):

Old question, I know, but perhaps someone else finds this useful.

Chrome accepts the following command line flag:

```
--simulate-outdated-no-au='Tue, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 GMT'
```

I don't know how you are initializing the chrome driver. Assuming Java, you should be able to add those startup options like: (Source: [Selenium Chrome Driver Arguments](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browsers/chrome/#arguments))

```java
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--simulate-outdated-no-au='Tue, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 GMT'");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

It disables the update checks and notifications and should therefore prevent it from ever updating (as long as it's always started with this flag). 
You can set a future date. This will let chromium think that it shouldn't be outdated until this date, and therefore won't show the outdated message.

Source: 
By Adalbert Michelic adalbert@lopez.at
"It's possible to silence this notification by faking the build date by using this command line parameter: --simulate-outdated-no-au='Tue, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 GMT'" https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=943668#15