# Standalone chrome.exe connection to selenium test

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

As you can find at [cannot stop Chrome from updating from 43 to 44](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31708631/cannot-stop-chrome-from-updating-from-43-to-44) I am having problem with chrome 44, as RobW suggested (in comments) i got a stand alone chrome.exe which has the version that I need, but now I do not know how to connect it to my test application which is written by Selenium & JAVA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *point the "binary" to your standalone Chrome* using [`ChromeOptions`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html):

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
options.setBinary(new File("/path/to/chrome"));

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: His problem is the new version of Chrome came out before the webdriver for it was updated.

Comment: @ZackAllen nope, the OP downloaded a custom chrome executable and wants to automate it through selenium. I've paid attention to the previous questions Sina asked. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe Thanks for your help, I allready have "driverChrome = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);" how can I add this option to it too?

Comment: @SinaGolestanirad thanks, please try with the updated answer.

Comment: @alecxe now it is throwing this error : INFO: Command failed to close cleanly. Destroying forcefully (v2). org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog@55040f2f
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: chrome failed to start ....

Comment: @SinaGolestanirad okay, can you launch the binary manually, does it work?

Comment: @alecxe if by "launch the binary manually" you mean that   chrome pens if I double click on chrome shortcut on desctop ,then yes, but even when I uninstall it and install chrome 44 it still gives the same error