# Chrome Inspect Element crashing with Ripple Emulator

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-2013, ripple

I'm building a mobile application with Visual Studio 2013, using Ripple Emulator and Cordova.

Every time that I try to inspect an element (hitting `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `I`, `F12` or right clicking the page and selecting `Inspect element`) the Google Chrome closes and Visual Studio stops running the application.

Has anyone know why I'm unable to inspect elements inside the browser using Ripple Emulator?

Ps: Visual Studio 2013 has his own `DOM Explorer` but the experience is not the same as the Chrome Developer Tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple workaround is to start your project without debugging (Ctrl+F5) from Visual Studio. This will allow you to use the Chrome dev tools (F12 and so on) without killing the VS debugger process and therefore stopping your Ripple session.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue since upgrading to cordova tools update 3 with visual studio 2015 community edition - it *was* working fine before "upgrading"

I haven't found a reason why, but there is a workaround which is to start your debugging session (F5.. or whatever) then hop back to visual studio, then select "Detach All" from the debug menu. This, or use a different browser (Edge works fine in Windows 10, but I'm not used to it's interface).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There was a change in the chrome debugging API that prevents VS from inspecting the elements and changing the style.  Chrome version 43 will work.  You have to take some steps to keep it from auto updating.  The installer for chrome 43 is here:

https://dl.google.com/chrome/win/4ED6DD719811795B/43.0.2357.134_chrome_installer.exe

You will need to uninstall chrome, update the registry, then install chrome 43.  When you go to the about screen it should say updates have been disabled by the administrator.

Here are the registry changes:
    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Update]
    "Update{8A69D345-D564-463C-AFF1-A69D9E530F96}"=dword:00000000
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Policies\Google\Update]
    "Update{8A69D345-D564-463C-AFF1-A69D9E530F96}"=dword:00000000

This thread has more information on the changes needed to the registry to prevent the auto update:

[cannot stop Chrome from updating from 43 to 44](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31708631/cannot-stop-chrome-from-updating-from-43-to-44)

NOTE: this means you are not getting security updates on that install, only use this until the issue has been resolved in an upcoming patch.