# How to disable Google Chrome auto update (release 43)

Tags: windows, google-chrome, auto-update

I have an old offline installer (It should be the release 43) and I'm trying to disable the auto updates. Unfortunately, everytime Google Chrome is executed, the newer version is downloaded and installed. I found several pages about disabling Google Chrome autoupdates (Like this [How to disable Google Chrome auto update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483087/how-can-i-disable-google-chrome-auto-update)) but it seems that there are no solutions that's still works with the release I'm using. At the moment, the only way I found is that to disable the network connection. 
Is there any solution that works with Google Chrome release 43?

Answer (score 0):

This works for release 46 in Windows:

- Uninstall Chrome (Chrome should keep your personal data unless you expressly tell the uninstaller to delete).
- Find the %appdata%\Local\Google\Update folder. Rename this folder to whatever you wish (I add _Removethistexttoenable to the name because I have a bad memory).
- Install the desired version from your offline installer.

Now, Chrome fails to start the updater service and all is well.