# Chrome driver stopped working for Chrome browser version 54 with the latest Chrome driver 2.24

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Today the latest build for chrome browser version got installed automatically which is now 54.0.2840.71 m (64-bit). I am unable to drive the browser using the latest Chrome driver 2.24 with any version of Selenium. Help me solve this issue..?

Comment: its working fine for me with chromedriver `2.24`. and chrome version `54.0.2840.71 (64-bit)` in Mac OS.which OS are you using?

Comment: It's working for me on Windows 10 too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi I have fixed the issue. Chrome version 54 and below are compatible with the Chrome driver 2.24 and the Chrome versions above 54 need Chrome driver 2.27.

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same problem. The only solution I know of (for now) is to revert back to the previous version of Chrome before the update... if possible. Thankfully I had one machine that had the chrome.exe version I needed as the updated VMs had blown it away.

This helped me:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/UFSYuIr1-80/DivHmlqPDAAJ

However I did not have "old_chrome.exe" in the folder. I had the old version directory but the old corresponding exe was gone. If I had not found it on an un-updated PC I would have been screwed.

**Edit:** 
I also turned off all Chrome updates so I can control them from now on:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31939624/2246511

Answer (score 1):

You could get the latest chromedriver (2.25) from:
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

That has fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

The whole chain needs to be aliged to version which support what they control: Selenium -> Selenium Chrome Driver -> ChromeDriver -> Chrome.

**Regarding Chrome Driver:**

See the other answers for traditional installation.

For Apple / MacOS with Brew, you need to:

1. Open chrome, go to Chrome -> About Chrome -> check if there is a prompt to restart chrome to start using the new version.
2. Upgrade ChromeDriver through brew:

   ```
   brew cask upgrade chromedriver
   ```

The version of  `chromedriver` is nowadays aligned with Chrome, so Chrome 80 comes with ChromeDriver 80. It seems to appear in Brew very soon after Chrome.

**Regarding Selenium ChromeDriver**:
Don't forget to upgrade to the latest version of [selenium-chrome-driver](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver) (along with the rest of Selenium deps) which knows how to operate the latest ChromeDriver.