# session not created exception while running Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Till yesterday: The below code was working fine.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users../Applications/chromedriver");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("www.google.com");

Dimension dim = new Dimension(1280,5277);
driver.manage().window().setSize(dim);

driver.quit();
```

But today morning it started throwing:
**Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception**

I read several answers in Stackoverflow. I understood that this error is thrown if there is a version mismatch between the selenium webdriver and chrome driver. So I download the latest Selenium Webdriver(3.0.1 for java) and chromedriver(2.4).I get an error

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session

So reverted back to the version I was using(2.53 for selenium web driver, I get the same error.

I tried below solutions:

killing all the chromedriver processes.

Rebooting the machine.

`Eclipse->project clean`

Nothing helps

Comment: Chrome 54?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40240299/chrome-driver-stopped-working-for-chrome-browser-version-54-with-the-latest-chro

Comment: Thank you @jibbs! Yes it is Chrome 54. It is not the chrome driver version or Selenium web driver version. It is the Google chrome update. Reverted back to version 53, It worked.

Comment: Use chromedriver version 2.25 with Selenium 3, it works for me

Answer (score 1):

The first error you encountered was indeed caused by a mismatch in the binary version between Chrome and the WebDriver.

But you've already figured this out, so onto the issue, you are facing now:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session
```

This error implies that the ChromeDriver was unable to communicate with the existing Browsing Context i.e. Chrome Browser session.

This can be due to a variety of reasons as [discussed here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=732). But given those issues have been fixed in a more recent version of ChromeDriver, if you are still running into this issue now it's most likely due to explicit or implicit session deletion.

It's a common mistake where you delete the session, either by calling .quit() or by closing the last window or tab, then attempting to use the session again.

Example:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

session = webdriver.Firefox()
print("Current session is {}".format(session.session_id))

# Explicit session deletion
session.quit()

# OR

# Implicit session deletion (close window/tab)
session.close()

# Attempting to use the session here will throw the NoSuchSessionException
session.get("https://example.com")
```

Answer (score -1):

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users../Applications/chromedriver")

need to change in above Line 
System.setProperty("**W**ebdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users../Applications/chromedriver")

W should be capital letter

Answer (score -1):

Here is a bit of code I used with working with Selenium. Make sure your Chrome Driver is the correct version.

```
// Link to Chrome Driver
// This gives Selenium access to the Chrome Driver in the parent directory
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");

// Launches Driver
        final WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://google.com/");

// Maximizes Google Chrome window
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
```