# Chrome driver 2.24 is not working with Chrome browser version 54

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

My chrome browser version got updated automatically to 54.0.2840.71 (64-bit).And I am unable to run my testcases in Chrome.I have tried using Chrome Driver 2.24,It did not work for me.
   (For example if i run Test on gmail login,I am able to login to the application by giving username and password ,but after my gmail inbox got loaded ,I get a message ..Chromedriver.exe has stopped working)
I have downloaded chrome driver 2.24 from here (http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.24/)And my log says Starting ChromeDriver 2.24.417431
Please help me solve this issue..?
Please let me know which versions of selenium webdriver you are currenlty working with Chrome Driver 2.24..Thanks in advance

Comment: You are not alone. Hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40240299/chrome-driver-stopped-working-for-chrome-browser-version-54-with-the-latest-chro

Comment: Are you using the latest version of selenium server?

Comment: No..I am using 2.47.1.But now my script is running fine after downloading chrome driver from the link Moe Ghafari suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the latest chrome driver(2.25) from here:
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/

Comment: No Problem. Been struggling for the past few days since i upgraded to Selenium standalone 3.0.1 with such issues; so glad i could help