# Selenium: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException:

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

```
package facebook;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class facebook {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\5558\\eclipse-workspace\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys("abcdefg@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pass']")).sendKeys("selenium123");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_2']")).click();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

I am getting this error as [Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AEw2.png)

Comment: Can you please specify the selenium version you are using and geckodriver version please

Comment: Also, firefox version please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome driver stopped working for Chrome browser version 54 with the latest Chrome driver 2.24](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40240299/chrome-driver-stopped-working-for-chrome-browser-version-54-with-the-latest-chro)

Comment: I pray to god that isn't your real FB id and password

Comment: @404BrainNotFound I'm sure that some people checked it already :D

Comment: @RafałSokalski that's y i said `pray`, bcz thats all that can be done now :D

Answer (score 0):

separate your code like this [Difference between @Before, @BeforeClass, @BeforeEach and @BeforeAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295578/difference-between-before-beforeclass-beforeeach-and-beforeall)

and get driver setup to @BeforeClass and `driver.quit();` to @AfterClass.

and don't post credentials here, even if fictional.