# Chrome Driver Server is not able to launch Chrome browser

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using ChromeDriver v2.24 and I have Chrome browser 52 in my system (not installed, executable file).

When I am executing my selenium script, the Chrome Driver is getting executed, but the Chrome browser is not getting launched. Because of that, I am getting

> NoSuchSessionException: no such session

Console:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf) on port 27796
Only local connections are allowed.
Jun 02, 2017 11:17:46 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Note: My script was working fine when I was using ChromeDriver 3.1 and Chrome 58 before the Windows security update. Post update I am not able to launch the Chrome browser as it's not launching the browser but running in the background.

Comment: Try using latest chromedriver

Comment: @SHalan Can you consider updating us your exact Selenium, chromedriver & Google Chrome version? Consider updating the question with your code block and error stack trace for further analysis. Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB I am using Selenium 3.4.0 and Chrome Driver 2.24 and that is the complete stock trace. My code was working fine before the security update with the Chrome browser version 59.

Comment: @SHalan The error says it all `SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".` Never mind of the security updates. Please consider to download the latest version of chromedriver i.e 2.29 and execute your script. In case you are stuck, update your code block in the Question Area as well. Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB Thanks! it worked!

Comment: @SHalan Great news !!! Should I consider to construct an Answer for you to Accept? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB Yes sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

1. As the logs depict till `INFO: Detected dialect: OSS` all was fine with your code.
2. Next we observe `SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".` which means the issue is with the loading of the class.
3. You have mentioned `My script was working fine when I was using ChromeDriver 3.1 and Chrome 58 before the Windows security update`
4. So the solution would be to download the latest ChromeDriver 2.29 from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) and re-execute your script.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove all Chrome browser instances from the system and install Chrome browser v52-54 which is supported by your chromedeirver 2.24.
Without installing a Chrome v52-54 crhomedriver is not able to launch it.

Make sure this is currently installed version and it's not updated automatically when the browser starts. You may need to [disable Google Chrome auto update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483087/how-to-disable-google-chrome-auto-update)