# Disabling infobar in chrome 65

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to run an automation script, once i ran a yellow bar appeared at the top on the screen."CHROME IS CONTROLLED BY AUTOMATED TEST SOFTWARE"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEGIl.png)

and my scripts stopped running.
I then updated the chrome driver to 2.36, now the scripts are running yet the bar is still visible.

```
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
chromeOptions.add_argument('--test-type')
chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, chrome_options=chromeOptions)
```

Comment: so i uninstalled chrome 65 and installed 63 and switched off the automatic update. Now everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for it. I downloaded chrome driver 2.37 and disabled the auto-update of chrome [Link to disable chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483087/how-to-disable-google-chrome-auto-update). Uninstalled chrome65 from system. and reinstalled a lower version. Then my scripts started working.