# How to update Chrome browser using python on Windows?

Tags: python, google-chrome

I have written a python script to open few pages with chrome, but sometimes I have issue with compatibility with chrome driver and chrome browser.
And I want to have updated version of both chrome browser and driver for my requirement.
So is there a way I can update Chrome browser using python ?

EDIT : I want it for Windows.

Comment: Linux or Windblows? (Leading question :P)

Comment: Windows .. updated the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

*You took too long to specify whether you were on windows or *nix.. so i took the linux route, who develops on windows anyways? :P Any who.. just convert this to batch file or powershell??? script...*

Normally I stick this inside a `install.sh` that does this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Install virtualenv
virtualenv venv

# Install python dependencies
venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt

# Install chromedriver
cd venv/bin/
curl -s https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.9/chromedriver_linux64.zip
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
rm chromedriver_linux64.zip
```

This will setup the entire environment, your virtualenv need is taken care of and your chrome driver too.

Comment: but this will do the trick for chromedriver but wont update the browser, right ?

Comment: @Rahul update the browser? No, Chrome autoupdates, there is no need to update it manually.

Comment: I want to control it, so I want to check if chrome is updated or not, if its not update it first and then run my script.

Comment: @Rahul, i dont think you can control that, you can get the version of chrome.. and compare it to the current version of chrome (doing a curl and some parsing), but i highly doubt you can tell chrome NOT to update.

Comment: I stand corrected. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483087/how-to-disable-google-chrome-auto-update there is a away to disable it.

Comment: My two cents. Don't bother, let it autoupdate, the chromedrivers are very stable, you can use old drivers with new versions without issues (ive been on 2.35 for a long time and theyre by 2.9 -- 0 issues, as a matter of fact i just realized how behind i was because i havent needed to update, my script still works like a champ)

Comment: great !! let me try