# Stop Chrome from Updating 2021

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

I am running Selenium code that does a very specific job. I would like to keep it running without getting Chrome updated because updating always breaks the code. I have done the following:

I have eliminated any service with "google" in its name.

I have put an entry

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Update\AutoUpdateCheckPeriodMinutes to the REG_DWORD value of "0".
```

I don't have an Updated folder for Google in Program Files (x86)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable Google Chrome auto update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483087/how-to-disable-google-chrome-auto-update)

Comment: No. I am living with updates for now.